# Laravel cron job is not running

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, cron

This is my first time setting up Cron job and I cannot make it to automatically schedule a command.

So I have a command:

```
public function handle()
{
    $client = new Client();
    $crawler = $client->request('GET', 'http://www.oldham-chronicle.co.uk/news-features');
    $crawler->filter('div[id=content]>.homefeature')->each(function ($node, $key) {
        $title = $node->filter('.plain')->text();
        $datepublished = $node->filter('.dateonline')->text();
        $description = $node->filter('.teaser-link')->text();
        $link = $node->filter('a')->link();
        $link_r = $link->getUri();
        $image = $node->filter('img')->image();
        $image_s = $image->getUri();
        $filename = basename($image_s);
        $image_path = ('news-gallery/' . $filename);
        Image::make($image_s)->save(public_path('news-gallery/' . $filename));
        $id = 1+ $key + 1;
        $news = News::where('id', $id)->first();
        // if news is null
        if (!$news) {
            $news = new News();
        }
        $news->title = $title;
        $news->datepublished = $datepublished;
        $news->description = $description;
        $news->link = $link_r;
        $news->image = $image_path;
        $news->save();
    });

    $crawler->filter('div[id=content]>.teaser-50')->each(function ($node, $key) {
        $title = $node->filter('.plain')->text();
        $datepublished = $node->filter('.dateonline')->text();
        $description = $node->filter('.teaser-link')->text();
        $link = $node->filter('a')->link();
        $link_r = $link->getUri();
        $image = $node->filter('img')->image();
        $image_s = $image->getUri();
        $filename = basename($image_s);
        $image_path = ('news-gallery/' . $filename);
        Image::make($image_s)->save(public_path('news-gallery/' . $filename));
        $id = 1+ $key + 1;
        $news = News::where('id', $id)->first();
        // if news is null
        if (!$news) {
            $news = new News();
        }
        $news->title = $title;
        $news->datepublished = $datepublished;
        $news->description = $description;
        $news->link = $link_r;
        $news->image = $image_path;
        $news->save();
        $this->info('Scraping done succesfully');
    });
}
```

Kernel file:

```
protected $commands = [
    'App\Console\Commands\NewsScrape'
];

/**
 * Define the application's command schedule.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
 * @return void
 */
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('scrape:news')
             ->everyMinutes();
             ->emailOutputTo('some@email);
}
```

I can manually run it as php artisan scrape:news and it works, however when I add it to crontab -e:

```
* * * * * php /var/www/fyproject/ schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Cronjob never runs, any help!

Comment: It should be `php /var/www/fyproject/artisan schedule:run`

Comment: Haha nice error put it as a answer and I will mark it ;)

Comment: No joke, I made the exact same mistake the first time I tried to set it up too.

Comment: One reminder ... you can go to the terminal, and type that command. In my case my laravel.log had the wrong permissions, and i could debug that in this way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command needs to be invoked via `artisan` so you must remember to add it in the call:

Use:

```
crontab -e * * * * * php /var/www/fyproject/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: How to check if this is working or not, please help @apokryfos